# nRF24L01+ module channel sensitivity and directivity

Tags: transceiver, sensitivity

I want to start a project where I distribute many nRF24L01+ modules across the house. I am pretty sure someone has done that before. But before I wanted to begin I evaluated the modules using two Arduino UNOs and noticed two things:

- Despite the possibility to select one of 126 RF channels. I get no reception on most of them.

  First I thought that is because of interference with other WiFi and Bluetooth devices. So I performed a scan using the RF24/Scanner sketch. But it wasn't it.

  I made a setup where I placed both transceivers on a table with 1m distance and played Ping-Pong. For each channel I sent out 1024 messages, counted the received messages on the other node as well the returned ACKs and ACK payloads.

  The result was rather surprising. Less than a half of all the channels are reliable.

  [image: facing away - number of received messages]

  The sad thing is that those channels are also the most commonly used by WiFi networks.
- That brought me to the second point. I thought the PCB antenna on the module might be not optimal for all frequencies but for one. So I made some research on PCB antennas. A [PDF from Cypress](http://www.cypress.com/file/136236/download) on p. 13 suggests that the PCB antenna is emitting most of its energy to the right. But on my setup I had them facing away from each other.

  I rerun the test with a different orientation of the modules. This time facing each other. I expected to get a wider range of channels that are usable this way. But it turned out the other way around.

  [image: facing each other - number of received messages]

So now I'm wondering if someone ever noticed the spectral sensitivity and directivity of nRF24L01+ modules and/or can point me to.

Comment: It is a very good question (I don't know the answer), but it belongs to Electronics stack exchange.

Comment: I’ve heard that those module don’t work very well at very short distances. Either move them further apart, or lower the transmit power (RF24.setPALevel()).

Comment: That did the trick for me. Now I have 100% reception on all 126 channels. Where did you hear about that?
If you put your comment into an answer, I will be happy to accept that.